# Auto delete a record in table when date is expired?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how can I auto delete a record when date is expired, I'm creating a Air-ticket booking website. I need to delete from my mysql database all the expired flight details. I read somewhere that I can use cron but I have no idea how to do it. Any Help for the script will be very helpful.

Comment: Why delete it. Just don't show it if it is expired

Comment: No need. Use dbms schedule. For example, MySQL has own [scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html).

Comment: use crone job to execute auto expiration script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try to use MySQL [`Events`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) for that:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `dbName`.`eventName`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY -- or 1 HOUR
COMMENT 'Description'
DO
    BEGIN
    
    DELETE FROM `dbName`.`TableName` WHERE `DateCol` < NOW();
    
    END
```

**NOTE** that MySQL [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html) need to be enabled on your server:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html).

Comment: do you know any reason why the >= value does not display TODAYs values? as if I am entering > without the =

Comment: @cmario it depends on what you actually comparing.

Comment: I found a way to do it
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` >= date(NOW()) .  Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Deleting records is not a good idea, I will suggest you Add ActiveFrom and ActiveTo  DateTime Column in your Details table then do not display the expired records in your front end.

Answer (score 0):

You need the service to check expired records and delete periodically. You should use this SQL:

DELETE YourTable WHERE RecordDate < @Expiration

Answer (score 0):

Cron is most suited in your situation.

- Create your php file that deletes or flag the unwanted flight, the script will simply connect to the database, execute your query, and maybe output a short success/failure message.
- Setup the cron job that executes that php script every X hours or whatever you want.

If you are using CPanel, you can setup your [cron job from it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBr47SVcymI)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **CRON** Jobs. Have a look at the below representation.

```
Minutes [0-59]  
|   Hours [0-23]  
|   |   Days [1-31]  
|   |   |   Months [1-12]  
|   |   |   |   Days of the Week [Numeric, 0-6]  
|   |   |   |   |  
*   *   *   *   * home/path/to/command/the_command.sh
```

If you want to schedule a task to run every Saturday at 8:30am , it would most probably look like this.

```
30 8 * * 6 home/path/to/command/the_command.sh
```

Just play around with your settings and you will eventually get it.

Answer (score 0):

If your table currently only has 2 fields, you'll need to add a timestamp field (with default as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) to be able to tell when the row was added.

Then you can run the following MySQL query...

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `timestamp` &gt; DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

;
You will need to run this as a cron though.

As far as I know, it can't be done in MySQL alone.