# How to delete a database row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, cron

I'd like to delete a row by ID number from a MySQL database after a specific amount of time have passed since the row was added to the database.

How can I do it? I'm a total beginner :)
Thank you.

Comment: Added the MySQL tag which will help finding answers more quickly. Rewrote the question to be more specific to what the person who's asking is actually wondering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181458/auto-delete-a-record-in-table-when-date-is-expired this is the same solution as you want. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `dbName`.`eventName`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY // or 1 HOUR
COMMENT 'Description'
DO
    BEGIN

    DELETE FROM `dbName`.`TableName` WHERE `DateCol` < NOW();

    END
```

turn on the [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html) before using events

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```